# trying results of 3 tables to single dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark

Im trying to get all columns from each table and store it in single dataframe by iterating in loop.
In below code run_query is a function which initiates a sql session.

```
def run_query(sql):
    query = <teradata driver details to connect to the database>
    return query

source = ['login','signup','alert']

output=[]
for i in range(len(source)):
   q = "select * from {} sample 1".format(source[i])
   var = run_query(q)
   output.append(var)
print(output)
```

Im always getting only first table columns, but i need all 3 tables columns.

Output Expected: Concatenation of all 3 tables columns data.

Table1
a, b

table2
c , d

table3
e, f

output table
table
a, b, c, d, e, f

Comment: Where is `run_query` coming from? What do you think it returns? What does the actual output printed look like?

Comment: @Babu edit your code to show ```run_query``` code

Comment: You could just create three dataframes and add additional columns in each of them and do a union on them to get the required dataframe with all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You have three tables and you are reading data from these tables individually.
You can create dataframe for each of the individual table and then append the additional columns that you would be getting from other tables to this dataframe with some default value and then do union of all the three datafame to get the final single dataframe.
Here I am giving a default value of 0 but you can give anything like null as per your requirement and use case.

```
df1 = table1 data (Columns a,b)
df2 = table2 data (Columns c,d)
df3 = table3 data (Columns e,f)
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
finaldf1 = df1.withColumn("c",lit(0))
.withColumn("d", lit(0))
.withColumn("e", lit(0))
.withColumn("f",lit(0))
finaldf2 = df2.withColumn("a",lit(0))
.withColumn("b", lit(0))
.withColumn("e",lit(0))
.withColumn("f",lit(0))
.select("a","b","c","d","e","f") --doing select to maintain order of columns for doing union.
finaldf3 = df3.withColumn("c",lit(0))
.withColumn("d", lit(0))
.withColumn("a", lit(0))
.withColumn("b",lit(0))
.select("a","b","c","d","e","f")
finaldf = finaldf1.union(finaldf2).union(finaldf3)
```

you can do finaldf.printSchema to get the schema of the final dataframe.